# ASP.net HTMLDecode not working for Resource entries

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, resx, html-encode

I have a ASP.net MVC project, which utilizes resource entries (.resx) through out the project.

Few the resources fed, have HTML in it

```
example: Hello <b>World!</b>
```

With paragraphs href and more. As the resources are stored in an XML, the entries are HTMLEncoded

i.e the above example looks like this

```
eg: Hello &lt;b&gt;World!&lt;/b&gt;
```

Due to this, wherever the resources are displayed, the HTML formatting does not render, and instead the HTML is displayed as visible text.

I tried to use HttpUtility.HTMLDecode and Server.HTMLDecode, but both wont work.

What is wrong? Any other work around resources?

Comment: How are you accessing the Resources entries and writing the results onto your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the following work fine for me:

```
    <%= Resource.MyResource %><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, MyResource %>" /><br />
```

A Resource entry such as `<b>Text</b>` is displayed in bold by the browser.

Some Controls do automatic HTML encoding of their inputs. Could that be what's happening for you?

Comment: Yes, actually the resource if retrieved after HTMLDecoding, no need of HTMLDecode as well. Some of controls were doing the encoding again.